# Flutter Camera picture using Wireless Bluetooth device

Tags: flutter, camera, flutter-dependencies

I am building an application using flutter in which it shows the camera preview inside the app using the camera plugin and I have added a button that takes pictures and then sends to the backend to fetch the results. But now there is a requirement that the image should be clicked using the wireless bluetooth button. The bluetooth button is working on the normal camera but not working inside the app.

I am not sure what is the issue. I have added all the various permissions in my application both for android and ios.

Comment: I have created a standalone project [https://github.com/Abhi6722/flutter-camera](https://github.com/Abhi6722/flutter-camera) realted to this issue so that you can get a clear idea on what I am expecting.